# POST JSON data to simple rails application with curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, post, curl

I set up a simple new rails application with model entry, with attributes `title` and `content` using scaffolding.

now I am trying to use curl to POST the JSON data (rather than using the browser).

the following seems to work (i.e. successfully posted with null data):

```
curl --verbose --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data "" http://localhost:3000/entries
```

the following does not work:

```
curl --verbose --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data "{'content':'I belong to AAA','title':'AAA'}" http://localhost:3000/entries
```

I have tried many variations.  the errors I get are mostly host not found or unexpected token at the JSON data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To go along with what Jonathan said, the Post is now sending the data to the EntriesController.  Now in your `create` action you have to get the data from the `params` hash.  I am going to assume you are doing it the railsy way and so you would do something like this:

```
    curl -d 'entry[content]=I belong to AAA' -d entry[title]=AAA http://localhost:3000/entries'
```

In your controller

```
    Entry.create(params[:entry])
```

This says grab the "entry" data from the params hash (created by rails for you) and pass it as a parameter to Entry to initialize a new Object.  "create" will do a "new" and "save" for you in one method call.

Comment: problem solved.  thanks so much.  Jonathan did get us started on the right track.  thank.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a test and got the error `MultiJson::DecodeError (743: unexpected token at '{'content':'I belong to AAA','title':'AAA'}'):`

JSON requires double quotes for keys and strings, not single quotes. Try `--data '{"content":"I belong to AAA","title":"AAA"}'`

Comment: thanks but still getting 743 error even with your suggestion.  I am wondering if somehow the application is not expecting or liking this json data I am trying to POST.  it is a simple rails app created by rails new and the model is by rails generate scaffold.

Comment: Actually, this solution assumed you wanted to pass JSON in the body of the request, which is different from POSTing data like a browser does. To mimic a browser, just use `curl -d 'content=I belong to AAA' -d title=AAA http://localhost:3000/entries`

Comment: Started POST "/entries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-09 07:46:48 -0500
  Processing by EntriesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"content"=>"I belong to AAA", "title"=>"AAA"}
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "entries" ("content", "created_at", "tit
le", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 0
9 Nov 2011 12:46:48 UTC +00:00], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 09 Nov 2011
 12:46:48 UTC +00:00]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/entries/46
Completed 302 Found in 0ms

Comment: as you can see, it started posting, but in the end, the data added is nil.

Comment: I should clarify I am in a windows 32 environment.

Answer (score 0):

take a block of JSON

```
{\"a\":\"this_is_a\"}
```

and url encode it

```
%7B%22a%22%3A%22this_is_a%22
```

and then use curl to post it

```
curl -i --data "working_params=%7B%22a%22%3A%22this_is_a%22" http://url/accepts/json
```

Comment: Time to explore. Try: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to get you started.