# POST empty when curling JSON

Tags: php, json, post, curl

I'm using curl to send this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d "{firstname:james}" http://hostname/index.php
```

I'm trying to display POST like this in index.php

```
<?php
die(var_dump($_POST)); 
?>
```

Which outputs

```
array(0) {
}
```

I must be misunderstanding something about sending JSON data via POST

Thank you for your time

Comment: I agree: you're not setting your JSON/HTTP post data correctly.  Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045260/post-json-data-to-simple-rails-application-with-curl

Comment: I think you need to quote the variables as they are strings not numbers

Comment: @Waygood Indeed, that too. The JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`$_POST` is an *array* that is only populated if you send the POST body in URL encoded format. PHP does not parse JSON by itself automatically and hence does not populate the `$_POST` array. You need to get the *raw POST body* and decode the JSON yourself:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$values = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Turns out it should be '{"firstname":"james"}'

Answer (score 10):

`$_POST` only works if you are sending encoded form data.  You are sending JSON, so PHP cannot parse it into the `$_POST` array.

You need to read directly from the POST body.

```
$post = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$data = json_decode(stream_get_contents($post));
fclose($post);
```